Using std::weak_ordering (with starship operator) for the first time, would this work?
I'm practicing using std::weak_ordering (along with starship operators) for the first time (assume all the getters and function calls here work), and what I'm trying to create here is a function that sees if both the Dogs' attributes (string name, string breed, string color, and double age) are equal.
If one of those attributes isn't equal, then it should be false (overall).
std::weak_ordering Dog::operator<=>( const Dog & rhs ) const noexcept
{  
  if ((_name <=> rhs.name()) == 0) {
    if ((_breed <=> rhs.breed()) == 0) {
      if ((_color <=> rhs.color()) == 0) {
        return is_same_age(_age, rhs.age());
      }
    }
  }
}

My question is this, what I should specifically return if that is the case (if one of the attributes are not equal)? Or perhaps would this just work on its own?
By the way, is_same_age is a separate boolean function that just compares the ages of the dogs (since if I wanted to use <=> on it, it would have to be std::partial_ordering, as far as I am aware).

I am new to it too, (_name <=> rhs.name()) == 0 isn't the same as _name == rhs.name()?

This will not work and will result in undefined behavior - the function promises to return a value but does not do that in all cases.

So what should I return in this case? Thats what i'm unsure of.

<=> is in general slower than ==, it doesn't replace it. (E.g. for strings, == can check the size early and stop if it's not equal, while <=> has to find the first mismatching character.) So writing == in terms of <=> isn't the best idea. And if your goal is to compare for equality, the method should be named operator==, not operator<=>, and return bool.

You are returning a value that specifies some kind of order among the potential arguments. But checking only for equality does not tell an order.

An ordering is a very different concept from equality.

Offtopic: defining relation operator for this kind of data is strange and confusing, since such data has multiple possible arbitrary orders. IMO it would be best not to define such relation operator.

"what I'm trying to create here is a function that sees if [definition of equality]." -- Defining when two objects are equal is an important step, but that gives you neither the starship operator nor an ordering. You're missing a definition of what it means for one object to be less than another (and also "greater than", but that can be inferred from "less than").

If you want to check whether 2 object are equal you should not use operator<=> (formally known as three-way comparisson) but rather operator==.
operator<=> is meant for estabshiling order between the objects, and it is quite clear that you don't need that (and having difficutly to even define the proper order).
Therefore you should use something like:
bool Dog::operator==( const Dog & rhs ) const noexcept
{  
    if (name() != rhs.name()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (breed() != rhs.breed()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (color() != rhs.color()) {
        return false;
    }
    return is_same_age(age(), rhs.age());
}

In addition to the semantical difference, as @HolyBlackCat commented above, it is not advisable to implement operator== in terms of operator<=>.

You might want this operator<=>, that returns a result in all cases.
std::weak_ordering Dog::operator<=>( const Dog & rhs ) const noexcept
{
  auto cmp = name() <=> rhs.name();
  if (cmp == 0)
    cmp = breed() <=> rhs.breed();
  if (cmp == 0)
    cmp = color() <=> rhs.color();
  return cmp;
}

It's unclear what is_same_age() returns, so I skipped it.

If find it equally unclear how color compares. Is spotted less than brown? :-)

Use of std::tie makes this implementation simpler and less bug prone:
std::weak_ordering Dog::operator<=>( const Dog & rhs ) const noexcept
{  
    return std::tie(    name(),     breed(),     color(),     age()) 
       <=> std::tie(rhs.name(), rhs.breed(), rhs.color(), rhs.age());
}

Or since this relations operator for structure of this type is strange and confusing (there is more the one way to define such relations depending on context), maybe you should just define an operator== using same approach:
bool Dog::operator==( const Dog & rhs ) const noexcept
{  
    return std::tie(    name(),     breed(),     color(),     age()) 
        == std::tie(rhs.name(), rhs.breed(), rhs.color(), rhs.age());
}

